# Problem to access members in pointer struct located in another pointer struct

Tags: c, struct, member

I'm getting some trouble to accessing members inside structures.

I have a Student and a Cursus struct, they are defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int* _notes;
    int _moyenne;
}Cursus;

typedef struct {
    Cursus* _mycursus; //1 francais, 2 english, 3 math
    char nom[255];
    char prenom[255];
    char classe[3];
}Student;
```

In the main.c I have created this:

```
Student * mystudents = (Student*) calloc(9,sizeof(Student));
```

But I cannot access to members with the index
This will never work for example:

```
mystudents[index]->nom
```

So i found another way to do it

```
(mystudients+index)->nom
```

And this is working perfectly !

Now the problem that I have is the next one:
I'd like to do this:

```
(mystudients+index)->(_mycursus+indexcursus)->_notes = (Cursus*)calloc(1,sizeof(Cursus);
```

And it doesn't work because it doesn't accept the fact that I add brackets to "_mycrusus".
How can I select the correct cursus if I can't do this ?

Thanks for your help,

Impact

Comment: `mystudents[index].nom` and `mystudents[index]._mycursus[indexcursus].notes`

Comment: Use the dot-notation because `mystudents[index]` identifies a structure, not a pointer.

Comment: Swap `->` for `.` and that's it. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: `mystudents[index]` designates a `Student` object, **not** a pointer to a `Student` object. So `mystudents[index].nom` must be used.

Comment: `[...]` operates as a *dereference* leaving `mystrudents[index]` of type `Student` not type `Student*` making the `'.'` (dot) operator proper for member access instead of the `'->'` (arrow) operator.

Answer (score 5):

In C, `x[i]` is identical to `*(x + i)`. In your case, the type of `mystudents[index]` is `Student`, not `Student*`.

Therefore, either use `(mystudents + index)->nom` or, more conventionally, `mystudents[index].nom`.

The same goes for other members:

```
mystudients[index]._mycursus = calloc(1, sizeof (Cursus));
mystudients[index]._mycursus[0]._notes = calloc(3, sizeof (int));
```

etc.

Note that you should not cast the return value of `malloc`, `calloc` etc.

Comment: Note: in the `(x+i)->` syntax it would be `((mystudients +  index)->_mycursus + indexcursus)->_notes`

Comment: Or if compiling on the command line with the *Developer's Command Prompt*, `/Tc` specifies compiling the next source as **C** while `/TC` specifies compiling *All* sources as **C** as @KonradRudolph points out. In the VS20XX IDE, you can right-click your project and choose Options and C/C++ options to set the compile as... option.

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong syntax

it should be

```
((mystudients+index)->_mycursus+indexcursus)->_notes = (Cursus*)calloc(1,sizeof(Cursus);
```

Comment: May point out that `_notes` is type `int*` so allocating based on `sizeof (Curses)` may over-allocate storage for `int`'s and perhaps `sizeof(int)` would be proper. Additionally the `mystudents[index]._mycurses[indexcurses]._notes` as an alternative syntax with a suggestion of avoiding leading `'_'` on variable names may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, Visual studio force the cast Malloc/Calloc, you cannot compile without doing it. I made my problem simple to get some answers but in reality I sent the mystudents pointer in another function like this:
`void AjouterEleve(Eleve ** a_eleves)` 
because I wanted to modify the amounts of students without returning a value in the function. 
Thanks to the greatfull answers I got, I find out how to do it:

```
scanf("%d", &(*a_eleves)[i]._lescours[choix - 1]._notes[(*a_eleves)[i]._lescours[choix - 1]._nb_notes-1]);
```

(*a_eleves)[i]. was indeed the key when we receive a pointer of pointer in parameters !

Comment: You *can* (and should!) leave out the casts, but you may need to explicitly tell MSVC that you’re compiling a **C** file (rather than C++), by specifying the `/TC` command line option for `cl.exe` somewhere in the options. — Regarding the code in this answer: please don’t actually write this. It’s completely unreadable even for experts. Use local variables to split apart and simplify complex nested expressions.

Comment: Please do not use a C++ compiler to compile C code: The semantic differences between the two languages will bite you eventually.